# Plot a list using R

Tags: r, list, plot

I would like to know how to plot a list.

Now I have a list

```
[[1977]] keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, ...
[[1978]] keyword2, keyword5, ...
...
[[2018]] keyword1, keywords3, ...

length(mylist) = 2018
lengts(mylist) = 0,0,0,0,0,......
dput(head(mylist)) = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

And I would like to plot it using keywords' frequencies as the y-axis and 1977~2018 as the x-axis.

So it should have many lines equal to the number of the keywords. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Look at `?sapply()`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? Edit your question and post your code.

Comment: @NelsonGon Thank you for the suggestion! I will look it up.

Comment: @ETO I'm sorry that so far I don't have idea how to start it. After trying I will update my progress

Comment: Could you add the output of `length(myList)` and `lengths(myList)`?

Comment: @Amy Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and pay attention to section "Search, and research"

Comment: @zx8754 I add it but don't know whether it will help. I don't know why lengths return many zeros but I'm sure that every [[i]] in the list have some keywords in it. The lengths are not the same

Comment: Could you also add, `dput(head(myList))`, if data is confidential then create some dummy example data, see [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: @zx8754 Thank you for your suggestion! I am trying to make another list to record the frequency in each year for each word now. I think after making that list I can plot line for each element in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this example:

```
# example data
set.seed(1); myList <- list(sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE),
                            sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE),
                            sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE),
                            sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE),
                            sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE))
names(myList) <- 1977:1981


library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

plotDat <- stack(myList) %>% 
  mutate(myYears = as.numeric(as.character(ind)),
         myWords = values) %>% 
  group_by(myYears, myWords) %>% 
  summarise(myCount = n())

ggplot(plotDat, aes(x = myYears, y = myCount, col = myWords)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use `data.table::rbindlist()`  to create a long data.table. Summarise to a frequency-table to plot with `ggplot`-functions

```
# using example data from @zx8754's answer.

library( data.table )
library( ggplot2 )

dt <- data.table::rbindlist( lapply( myList, as.data.table ), idcol = "year" )
dt <- dt[, .N, by = list(year, V1) ]
ggplot( data = dt, aes( x = year, y = N, group = V1, fill = V1 )) + geom_col( color = "black" )
```

[image]

Comment: I think they want a line plot.